# How do I find out the code coverage of the JDK caused by my tests?

Tags: java, testing

I am currently using Emma as the code coverage tool for my project. I know how to get the code coverage analysis of running a sample Java test case. This will give me the code coverage details of the Java test case code, but, what I want to know is how much JDK code was covered in running the sample Java test case.

For example, if my test case is:

```
public class TestCase{
 public static void main(String[] args){
  System.out.println("Hello world!");
 }
}
```

I want to know how much JDK code was executed to execute the above test case.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considere explicitely instrumenting the jars from the jdk and including com.sun; java. and javax packages?

Comment: HI,
I am using emma as an eclipse plugin. how do we achieve the above?

Answer (score 0):

try [cobertura](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/)